# generate a random number of length 25

Tags: c, random

eg: 1589745896214758962147852.

This is a question I have been slogging out for a while now.
What are the possible ways?
What is the best practice?

Comment: Does this preclude numbers with fewer than than 25 digits?

Comment: Yes. Can be 0000000000000000000152478

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a nice question...

You can use OpennSsl BIGNUM.

This is a simple fatorial example.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <openssl/bn.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    BIGNUM *fat;
    BN_ULONG a, f;
    char *resp;
    int i;

    fat = BN_new();

    for (i = 1; i < argc; i++) {

        f = atoll(argv[i]); 

        BN_dec2bn(&fat, "1"); 
        for (a = 2; a <= f; a++) {
            BN_mul_word(fat, a);
        } 

        resp = BN_bn2dec(fat); 

        printf("Fatorial of %s = %s\n", argv[i], resp);
    }
    return 0;
 }
```

I just dicovered a better example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <openssl/bn.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    BIGNUM *fat;
    char *resp = NULL;

    fat = BN_new();

    BN_generate_prime(fat, 80, 1, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);

    resp = BN_bn2dec(fat);

    printf("Big Random Value: %s\n", resp);

}
```

;)

Answer (score 7):

You could just call  the random number generator 25 times for each digit - simple if you want this as a string.

If you don't have a random number function available there is a simple to implement one.
[image]

http://xkcd.com/221/

Comment: @Clifford it's cc non-commercial (same as SO) but the SO image cache removed the link in the image so I've added one

Comment: You did the right thing but. CC does not of course mean copyright free, and in this case XKCD do require attribution.  That said I am right after the fact since I was only half serious in the first instance.

Comment: @Clifford - yes I thought the image was still a link but SO now caches them on a CDN.  ps I tested this code and I got a 3 with my dice!

Answer (score 1):

You will have to deal with a string for saving your number.

Because the signed long long min is -9223372036854775808 and max is 9223372036854775807.

1589745896214758962147852 is much more long.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is ill defined (at time of writing).

If you need exactly 25 digits then you can simply iterate 25 times getting a random number from 0 to 9 and compiling them into a string of digit characters.

If it must be a 25 digit number (i.e. 10<sup>25</sup> <= r <= 10<sup>26</sup>-1) rather than 25 random digits then the first digit must >= 1 (no leading zeroes).

If you require these digits to represent an integer value, upon which you may perform arithmetic operations, rather than a string of digits, then you will be out of luck with C's built-in data types on any likely platform since the value will require at least 85 bits (10<sup>25</sup>/log(2)).

You can build a 85 bit representation by concatenating the bits returned from a standard random number generator into a byte array If using the standard C library rand() function check your implementation's RAND_MAX value; some implementations only generate 16 bits, so some care is needed to concatenate them since it may not be a whole word of random bits.  However to arithmetically manipulate such a number you will have to create arithmetic functions to do that too (or use a "bignum" library).